# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: wireless

Recently got a new laptop Acer Aspire E14 (E5-491G-78F8) and installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on it. I am not able to get wifi working on it.

Details are here 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13736305/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

`$ ifconfig`

```
root@subu-Aspire-E5-491G:/home/subu/wireless# ifconfig eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:cb:18:9a  
          inet addr:192.168.0.198  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f276:1cff:fecb:189a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:258249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:136361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:319411776 (319.4 MB)  TX bytes:20380324 (20.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:13401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1753814 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1753814 (1.7 MB)
```

Comment: Just enable Wi-Fi from network panel

Comment: there is no option to enable wifi.  btw, wifi works perfectly on windows in the same machine.

Comment: I meant enable networking

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706581/no-wifi-in-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the wireless script result indicates you have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

```
Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

This has been recently fixed upstream, follow the instructions to install the backported modules and needed firmware

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/15/backports-20151115.tar.gz
tar zxvf backports-20151115.tar.gz
cd backports-20151115
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

And it should work after a reboot

If you have a kernel update and wireless quits again you will need to

```
cd backports-20151115
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it worked ..  yep . it was 14.03 ..  my bad

Comment: @Jeremy31: This solution worked perfect for me, and I am posting this comment via Wifi :) I have a Acer Aspire E5-573-5108.

Just a quick note though, I noticed that there is no target by the name 'defconfig-wifi' in the 'Makefile' of the directory. But somehow it still worked.

Comment: @RockyInde , the target is actually in the defconfigs folder and some newer backports no longer have wifi or ath10k for an option