# Onboard wifi Adapter not working on Lenovo300 i5 skylake

Tags: wireless, drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a new, clean, Lenovo i5 Skylake Laptop.

The built in wifi adapter doesn't seem to be working. 
I used an Edimax stick, which was identified instantly, to access the web. Tried updating, upgrading, nada.

Any ideas?

> lev@PC:~$ lspci -nn | grep -i net
>
> Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit
>   Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15) 02:00.0 Network controller
>   [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]:

Comment: Please, open a terminal window (Ctrl-Alt-T) then run the command `lspci -nn | grep -i net`, copy any text it shows, then paste it in your question.

Comment: That worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed this:
[Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/ubuntu-14-04-windows-wifi-driver-installation)

Specifically the post by Jeremy31 that starts with:

> You do not need Windows drivers and ndiswrapper
>
> This has been recently fixed upstream, follow the instructions to
>   install the backported modules and needed firmware

Worked like a charm. :) Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please don't answer by linking to other answers on this site, but use the [flag] button to flag the question as a duplicate (once you get a little bit more rep)  **;-)**