# No wireless for lenovo flex 3 1480

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my new flex 3 1480. I do not see wireless option. I tried the solution mentioned in [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305201&page=2) post but it doesn't work. Output of the wireless script can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14441796/) . 
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I tried the above solution but it still doesn't work

Comment: Run the wireless script again and post the new URL

Comment: Please find the new script output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/14474183/

Comment: What happens when you `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci`

Comment: running the above command doesn't give me any output, not even an error.

Comment: What is the `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` after that command?

Comment: `02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4035]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3835]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
`

Comment: Reinstall the backports

Comment: Sorry for the naive question but by reinstall do you mean downloading the backports and installing  them again? Is there any 'uninstall' step involved? I did that again as mentioned in your  answer here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation?lq=1) but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result for `dkms status` as it might be the cause

Comment: `backath10k, 2.0, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
backath10k, 2.0, 3.19.0-25-generic, x86_64: installed
backath10k, 2.0, 3.19.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
`

Comment: `dpkg -r backath10k/2.0 --all`  Reboot and then try the answer in the duplicate post but use the instructions I added for after a kernel update, 5 lines of code