# Wi-fi Atheros pci.id 168c:0042, problem while wifi driver installation

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, kernel, atheros

I followed the steps suggested in the following solution: [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation?newreg=3eff43da3f774d0c80253b51e8269b9b)

But the terminal shows the following:`/--------------
| Your kernel headers are incomplete/not installed.
| Please install kernel headers, including a .config
| file or use the KLIB/KLIB_BUILD make variables to
| set the kernel to build against, e.g.
|   make KLIB=/lib/modules/3.1.7/
| to compile/install for the installed kernel 3.1.7
| (that isn't currently running.)`

What should I do.
PS: I'm a newbie in linux. So kindly keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: ubuntu 15.10, the latest one.

Comment: And what is the kernel version `uname -a`. It looks like toy have a completely wrong kernel installed.

Comment: Linux BlueHaze 4.2.0-28-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 1 23:09:27 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: On upgrading linux-generic, It says the current version is latest

Comment: Please add output of `ls /lib/modules` to your question. It is weird.

Comment: '4.2.0-27-generic  4.2.0-28-generic  4.2.0-31-generic'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the headers package. With a working internet connection, open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t and run:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then try your compilation again. Post any errors and we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a wrong kernel installed for 15.10.

If you did an upgrade from 15.04 that could happen, because of a bug.

You can fix it bu running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

This command will install `linux-headers-generic` and `linux-image-generic`. These packages will install the latest kernel and headers for Ubuntu 15.10.

Then reboot and try to install the drivers again.