# Not getting Enable WiFi option in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, atheros

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But Enable WiFi option is not coming. I have tried various commands to get the info as much as was possible for me.

Wireless Info Script Data

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 Feb 2016 23:31 IST +0530

Booted last: 02 Feb 2016 21:47 IST +0530

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0987]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b520 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 049: ID 03f0:5307 Hewlett-Packard 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi
video                  20480  2 i915,acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

bnep0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'bnep0' [IF]>  
      inet addr:192.168.44.105  Bcast:192.168.44.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'bnep0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:52936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:42944 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:56707473 (56.7 MB)  TX bytes:3471019 (3.4 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

bnep0     no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.44.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bnep0
192.168.44.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     11     0        0 bnep0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       802     1  0 21:47 ?        00:00:03 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: <MAC address>  [XT1033 Network] ----------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes

  Capabilities:

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.44.105
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.44.1

    DNS:             192.168.44.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN

##### iwlist channels ###################

bnep0     no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

bnep0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
```

Kindly help.... I have tried a lot... Not getting any way out.... Please help...... Thanks in advance....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qualcomm Atheros Device \[168c:0042\] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation)

Comment: @Pilot6 - thanks for the reference, friend, I will try to follow the instructions given in the referenced question, then will let you know.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I have done all the steps given in the referenced question and everything was done without any error. But still after rebooting the machine, I didn't get anything. My WiFi is still not working, all the things are as it is.
Kindly guide what should I do next.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Its updated @Pilot6

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake somewhere and did not install the driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 - I made a slight change in the process, while getting backport-20151120 and firing the command make deconfig-wifi, I got the error as Can't find default configuration defconfig/wifi. So on Googling, I found that some files are missing in the zip. So I picked this package https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.3/backports-4.3-1.tar.gz and further process went smooth.

Comment: This package might not work. I suggest first to upgrade kernel by `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily` then install the correct package again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35252/discussion-between-anuj-sharma-and-pilot6).

Comment: @Pilot6 - I have upgraded the kernel by linux-generic-lts-wily, and then did all the make commands, but still issue persists.

Comment: Let's wait for @Jeremy31 He may help

Comment: @Pilot6 -  Okay..... and the suggestion of using different package which I told about was suggested by Jeremy only in some other post. I wish he will help me out here.