# qualcomm atheros 168c0042-rev-30

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 16.04, atheros

i can't get my laptop WiFi up and running with ubuntu (Kernel 4.4.0-22-generic).

I have a Qualcomm Atheros 168c:0042 pci adapter.

Things I already tried:

- The solution from this question (installing the firmware from git repo):
  [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation?newreg=6c469f8b44c24d84bc72215697bb2c7a)
- I also tried using another Kernel (4.5 & 4.6), which showed some result.
  There was a menu which i could use to connect to my WiFi, but i still
  could not use the connection (no internet).
- Install a backport (like described in the question above)
- Format c:

Is there something new i could try??? I'm kind of desperate, because i already invested round about 8-10 hours into the matter =/ Any help is appreciated!

---

## Infos:

cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 4.4.0-22-generic (buildd@lcy01-32) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) ) #39-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 5 16:53:32 UTC 2016
```

dmesg | grep ath10k

```
[    5.342231] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: pci irq msi interrupts 1 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    5.610265] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:02:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    7.859610] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: qca9377 hw1.0 (0x05020000, 0x003820ff sub 1a3b:2231) fw WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 fwapi 5 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features ignore-otp
[    7.859619] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    7.925725] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

sudo lshw -c network

`*-network

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 30
       serial: 80:a5:89:02:1a:d9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:317 memory:81000000-811fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: 80:a5:89:02:1a:d8
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.44.105 multicast=yes`

lshw -vvnn

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2231]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 317
Region 0: Memory at 81000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the kernel to linux-image-extra-4.13.0-1005-azure-edge

Worked first time:-)

Comment: are you sure the problem this solved for you was the same as OP's? Can you clarify at all?