# WiFi driver for Qualcomm Atheros rev[30]

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

My wifi is working fine on Windows 10 but it is not detecting in Linux.

I am facing the same problem as described in [qualcomm atheros 168c0042-rev-30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772989/qualcomm-atheros-168c0042-rev-30?rq=1&newreg=f08b4f23791b43c6b63e2b3284b35477)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu, which version?

Comment: Do you have any error messages in the system logs?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my laptop which has Qualcom wi-fi on Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS.

> 06:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

The issue was fixed when I updated to Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS. All I had to do was connect through cable and run `sudo apt update` & `sudo apt upgrade`