# WiFi No Longer Works after Installing Xubuntu 16.04 on a Microsoft Surface Pro 1st Gen

Tags: networking, drivers, xubuntu, 16.04, bios

This is quite exciting, my first post on ask Ubuntu.

Initially, the Wifi was working and then an update was pushed(I apologize, I don't remember the update that affected it) and for some reason, the Wifi only worked every now and then or seemed like the signal was very weak. I did my best to try and solve the issue by searching several hundred resources for the right answer and I got as far as trying to setup wpa_gui and the proper source to run it.

So, unfortunately I now do not receive any indication that networks are being picked up by the wireless adapter or anything. I also attempted to do a fresh install of Xubuntu to try and fix the issue but I also cannot get to my BIOS to set up booting from the MicroSd like I had installed it with.

I apologize if this is a noobish question but I really do need some help. If there are any pros out there that could walk through this lend me a hand I'd greatly appreciate it.

In case it is needed the PC is the Microsoft Surface Pro Gen 1 128GB.

Thanks in advance and I'll be watching out for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Connect device to an ethernet

```
     sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot
You do not need Windows drivers and ndiswrapper
This has been recently fixed upstream, follow the instructions to install the backported modules and needed firmware

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backport-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

And it should work after a reboot
It will fail when a new kernel is installed through updates until the kernel is patched to support the wifi. When that happens you will need to

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot

Source: [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation/708103#708103)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Hedwig. I do have the issue of no internet on the device though. Do you know of a way I can get this on another pc and then install it on the Surface pro?

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to mention you need to connect your device via ethernet

Comment: Dang... The Surface pro does not have an ethernet port... Not sure what to do besides going and buying a USB to ethernet adapter or something

Comment: ya that seems like the best option

Comment: Thanks for your help Hedwig, I'm most likely going to go and get one of those adapters and see if I can get this up and running. If that is the case then I will post an update here to give other people who have the same issue a lead on what to do. Also, do you know if there would be any issues if I were to just purchase a Wireless AC usb adapter? Does Ubuntu have any issues with those that you know of?

Comment: You could also do these steps by booting into a Live USB for Ubuntu and then chroot into your original installation. Read this for [getting started](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root).