# My wi-fi has very low range on 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04, windows-10

I am having a peculiar problem with my computer, I have HP Pavilion x360 Convertible with an Intel i3 chip. I've just downloaded 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 on this machine.

Ubuntu works great, except for one problem: my WiFi is not working, really. Whenever I'm in the same room as my router, it displays three bars, and works so-so/fine. However, anywhere further away than that, say, out of the room, the WiFi stops working. I get no reception.

This is an issue with Ubuntu, because when I'm on the Windows 10 software, my WiFi works anywhere in my house, full strength, very fast. For some reason, my wireless on Ubuntu is very weak.

Can I get some help with this? I'm really new to Ubuntu.

Comment: Please edit to include terminal results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend connecting the device to an ethernet

```
     sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

Reboot You do not need Windows drivers and ndiswrapper This has been recently fixed upstream, follow the instructions to install the backported modules and needed firmware

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) git
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.4.2/backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-4.4.2-1.tar.gz
cd backport-4.4.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

And it should work after a reboot It will fail when a new kernel is installed through updates until the kernel is patched to support the wifi. When that happens you will need to

```
cd backports-4.4.2-1
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot

Source: [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation/708103#708103)

Comment: ... what? So, which command do i do first? The first one or the second one?

Comment: do the first two

Comment: Hi there, I did what you said, ran those commands, and no effect has taken place. My connection still drops off after I move away from my router.

Comment: Have you tried the last segment.

Comment: 4.4 backports won't improve anything on 16.04 as it already has a 4.4 kernel

Comment: @Jeremy31 sorry should have mentioned the source