# My WiFi connection frequently stops working (no internet, not disconnecting)

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

My internet connection frequently stops working (I can't open any websites, ping does not work, online games disconnect, etc.) but my WiFi is still connected. I've only installed Ubuntu a few days ago, so I might just have noticed the problem now. I've also checked, that my other devices have a working internet connection, so I'm sure the problem isn't with my router.

[output of the wireless info script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17230157/)

EDIT:

- the problem occurs more than once per hour
- disconnecting from and reconnecting to WiFi temporarily fixes the problem
- rebooting the router does not fix the problem
- other devices are unaffected
- turning off power management does not fix the problem
- [lshw output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17232895/)
- The problem does not occur on Windows(dual-boot)
- fixing the routers WiFi channel does not fix the problem

Comment: How often does it stop working? Have you tried rebooting your WIFI router.From the pastebin everything seems ok to me.

Comment: It stopped working about 5 times this afternoon. I'll try to reboot the router and see if it works. EDIT: I noticed it not working about 5 times, but I assume it happened more often, as it only seems to last between one and five minutes.

Comment: And also try to see if the WIFI works on other devices at the time of disconnection .

Comment: I already did. Works on all other devices.

Comment: Just lost the connection again. It seems to occur every few minutes since I'm checking. Ping results in "Destination Host Unreachable".

Comment: Disconnecting and reconnecting WiFi seems to fix the problem temporarily.

Comment: Make sure power management is turned off , when you run `iwconfig wlan0` should display a line with `Power Management: Off`. If it says `On`, you have to run:

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`

Comment: I think i tried that earlier today and it didn't work, but I'll try again (rebooted since then). Also, It's not called wlan0, but wlp3s0. Is that unusual?

Comment: That is normal now in Ubuntu 15.10 and after.  Where did you get the firmware from?  I would guess you tried `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off` and checked the `iwconfig` results to see if power management turned off?

Comment: I can't remember where I got the firmware from. I think I just installed a package via apt-get, but it took me more than an hour and many tries to get the WiFI working, so I can't really remember. And yes, I used `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 power off` and checked aftwards.

Comment: Turning power management off didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you fix the channel of your WiFi router so it can not change. Maybe there are a lot of noise around so it is changing the operating channel frequently which results in your disconnection. I'm pretty sure that your laptop should handle those changes but lets be sure.

Comment: Fixing the channel actually stopped the connection and Ubuntu prompted me to reenter the password, so that shouldn't be the problem, but I'll check if it happens again.

Comment: I was expecting one and only connection lost when you change the WiFi channel at first. From now on, you should not be disconnected from router as long as you don't have another internal problem. However, asking a password for an already saved SSID is something strange.

Comment: Fixing the WiFi channel didn't solve the problem.

Comment: See if http://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation fixes the issue, if it does flag it as a duplicate

Comment: Out of suggestions. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have fixed itself on the next day, as it has not occurred in more than four hours.