# No wireless on Ubuntu 15.10 in Acer Aspire E15

Tags: wireless, 15.10, acer

We have Acer Aspire E15 computers running with Ubuntu 15.10 for students and I am preparing a course. 
I cannot access internet via wireless, only via ethernet.
The wireless specifications are posted on http://paste.ubuntu.com/17320121/

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Might be a good idea to use Ubuntu 16.04 as 15.10 will be unsupported in about 6 weeks

Comment: I can't see any modules loaded from lsmod. Just try this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation)