# Qualcomm Atheros - Slow/Not connecting on Ubuntu, but works in Win 10

Tags: wireless, atheros, ubuntu-minimal

I have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 network driver.

I am having very slow Wifi on my Linux OS but it works fine on Windows 10. When I use an ethernet cable everything works, but WiFi is slow and sometimes just doesn't connect.

Can anyone guide me on how I can fix this?

Here is some more information about my Driver:

```
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)

Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e08e]

Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+

Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx+

Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 35
Region 0: Memory at d1400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: I deleted my earlier comments to clean up the comment area, I would recommend doing the same. As for your issue, how did you  initially install the driver? This can be a good starting point, because some things might not have been installed correctly. Also, is there any sort of pattern as to when it doesn't connect? Like when having a certain application open or just after a reboot, etc. Please edit this information into your post, as well.

Comment: There isn't a pattern. The WiFi randomly chooses to work, other times it is very slow. I did nothing to install the driver and am simply using what came with Ubuntu-minimal.

Comment: Oh, well, that's a good starting point. I would recommend checking [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/708103/602680) out.

Comment: The link in the answer after the command wget leads me to a 404 error, and hence when I type the solution from the link into the terminal there is an error.

Comment: That file seems to be missing from the mirror, but I did find the link for the most recent version on the same mirror: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.127.22_all.deb

Comment: Do I just run the first code block from the link? I am a bit confused. Also, will this cause issues after an update?

Comment: No, it won't cause issues. Just run the first block, replacing the link with the one I provided.

Comment: Should just need to run `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware` for the newest version for xenial to be installed.  Ubuntu seems to have merged some new commits from the upstream linux-firmware.  Please edit the question to include results from `iwconfig`

Comment: I haven't run the install linux-firmware command. Should I?
@OwenHines In the link you provided the card is QCA9377. Wherever this is in commands, should I replace it with QCA6174, which is my network card?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: What are your thoughts on @Jeremy31 suggestion? There is also an answer listed below. I don't know which one to pick

Comment: I will say that your wireless card uses the ath10k_pci module, not ath9k or iwlwifi.  There has been a recent change in network manager that may be a contributing factor.  See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665) for info I would like to see

Answer (score 1):

Alright what you could do is try adding a line to your config

```
sudo su
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Then reboot your pc to see if this helped.
If this did not fix your speed issue I have another trick you could use.

Force disable the 802.11n protocol.
While the protocol is supposed to provide better speed with newer routers.
Most modern day routers actually do not use this protocol which can cause issues.

Open the terminal and use the following command:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwif
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Now try reconnecting to the net if this did not fix the issue then oh well but if it did then to make the change permanent issue these commands.

```
sudo su
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Hopefully this will have fixed your issue and if not I have one last thing you could do and that is to disable ipv6 while I am not sure your provider has ipv6 support sometimes this can cause issue with certain routers and ISP's to test if this is the issue

```
sudo su
echo "#disable ipv6" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

For any of the above just sudo gedit 'the filename and location' such as

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

Then fine the line which was added and remove it.

The second solution I provided a way to test to see if it helps before making it permanent so you wont need to do any manual edits to undo it unless you choose to do the step that makes the change permanent.

If nothing I provided helped please comment get back to me etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you briefly explain what your first solution is doing?

Comment: @AlexCooper can you add instructions to revert the changes that you are instructing the OP to make, just in case they don't work for him and so those changes aren't permanent.

Comment: @OwenHines added a sample line to show him how to open the the config in a text editor to remove the changes.

Comment: @vBoi the first solution is adding a config parameter for your wifi adapter that is disabling a feature which can sometimes cause issues for Atheros adapters. If none of these soultions works I will also guide you through downloading and compiling a new copy of the needed driver from wireless.kernel.org