# I'm having an issue while trying to fix my connection

Tags: networking, atheros

I have a Toshiba Satellite C-55 and recently changed to Ubuntu 19.10, I'm completely new to Ubuntu, so there's nothing much I know what to do, except googling before asking, but I'm stuck.
My internet connection got really slow like a day or so after installation, and IDK why, but I found out that is a common issue with Atheros devices, which my computer has, so I tried to enter the following command:

```
sudo su
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

As seen here: [Qualcomm Atheros - Slow/Not connecting on Ubuntu, but works in Win 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844846/qualcomm-atheros-slow-not-connecting-on-ubuntu-but-works-in-win-10?newreg=028cc1a45d44434990c04281462e0564)
But... it got stuck there, it's doing nothing (I think, but whenever I try to close the terminal, it's saying that there's still a process running, but it has been like that for an hour, what do I do?

Comment: The Ubuntu releases for desktop or servers have a *year.month* format, eg. 19.10 means the 2019-October release (*available in desktop or server*).  Yes some specialist releases do use a *year* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 is a specialist release for IoT appliances, but are not intended for generic use. For starters I'd suggest using a desktop or server release (*though specialist releases come out even years only; so please be specific as there is no Ubuntu 19*)

Comment: Done, fixed, 19.10