# Can't turn on wifi, Hard-blocked 16.04, HP 14

Tags: wireless, 16.04

When I open the connection setting then I press

[image]

"wifi key" , airplane mode switches on and off. When I switch the wifi toggle on wireless network, it turns off again, I mean I am not able to turn on the wifi.

```
farisul@farisul-notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 802.11b/g/n WiFi
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [103c:217f]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

How ca I fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thats it, I hope do it right

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/708103/15811 1st 4 lines of the answer

Comment: @Rinzwind  I try type the command and then "404 http not found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba Satellite several times, and solved it doing either:

1. If you have a dual boot with Windows, and you disable your wifi in Windows, in my case it also blocked the wifi for Ubuntu.
2. Sometimes the laptop just "hangs" on the hard-blocking and the only way is to remove your laptop battery, which resets the BIOS (my laptop does not have a cmos battery).

Answer (score 1):

First go into BIOS and reset it to defaults. If that does not help, then run in terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-hp.conf <<< "blacklist hp_wmi"
```

and reboot.

Comment: You my savior, thx very much, problem solved.... thank you thank you, god bless you

Comment: How did you solve it? By bios reset or blacklisting `hp_wmi`?

Comment: Before see your post, I get some advice from google tell me to reset bios, I I have done it, nothing change. Then I try your suggestion (blacklisting hp_wmi, and work well... But when I press the wifi button/key bluetooth is turned on/off too, so however now I can connect to wifi

Comment: Please add your laptop model to your question to let people know where it is applicable.