# Wifi connectivity issue in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless, hp, ralink, rfkill

I am not able to connect wifi in my laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Can some one let me know what could be the problem?

How can I check if my system does not have some software necessary for connecting wifi?

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) I am giving the information in wireless-info.txt file.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 May 2018 21:31 IST +0530

Booted last: 30 May 2018 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Sat May 19 10:58:46 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [103c:2211]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName:  
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c342 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. Media Keyboard K200
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800pci,rt2800mmio
rt2x00lib              57344  5 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              737280  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
cfg80211              565248  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7772:7d9f:ce67:a12c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3315 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2096422 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:420183 (420.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:62175 (62.1 KB)  TX bytes:62175 (62.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search domain.name

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       893     1  0 21:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:08:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       535d176d-5f49-341f-abd3-cda51608cc5b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{5}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   535d176d-5f49-341f-abd3-cda51608cc5b | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.4/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             202.88.238.3
IP4.DNS[2]:                             202.88.238.5
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1527702837
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.4
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = domain.name
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 202.88.238.3 202.88.238.5
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::7772:7d9f:ce67:a12c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::12be:f5ff:fe94:117f
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::12be:f5ff:fe94:117f/128, nh = ::, mt = 100

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800pci
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-127-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:09:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IITB-Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IITB-Guest | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=IITB-Guest | mac-address=
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HOME]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HOME | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=HOME | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mathematics III]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Mathematics III | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Mathematics III | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Titli]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Titli | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Titli | mac-address=
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2860.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 PCI & PCMCIA Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     A85C15B012046B471096C5F
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,eeprom_93cx6
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2800mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2800 MMIO library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     C6D1A5D54B56AB8E61D5A73
depends:        rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00mmio
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     9C888DC1E0B053A56F1B5D4
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211,crc-ccitt
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[rt2x00pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 pci library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     543B84557258F153AC267F0
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[rt2x00mmio]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00mmio.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 mmio library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     ADBE279820CFD0A1081C682
depends:        rt2x00lib
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     72E39180D883A5541F66494
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     6F6591120B0B257B6E5E85B
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-127-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     AF52F2B944842498D5E951F
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-127-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800pci]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac
blacklist mac80211
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist cfg80211
blacklist wl
blacklist lib80211_crypt_tkip
blacklist lib80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

modprobe brcm80211

modprobe brcm80211
exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x1814:0x3290 (rt2800pci)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    7.773660] systemd[1]: Started Trigger resolvconf update for networkd DNS.
[   13.522048] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3290, rev 0015 detected
[   13.530105] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 3290 detected
[   31.258680] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   31.265229] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   31.711324] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   31.711403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   33.272917] r8169 0000:08:00.0 eth0: link up
[   33.272929] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

```
sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi wmi

praphulla@praphulla:~$ rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN 
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: yes
```

any help to fix this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: According to `rfkill` the wireless adapter on you system is disabled through a hardware switch and/or vendor-specific kernel module. Could you please (1) search and enable the wireless switch on your laptop computer and (2) run `sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi wmi` and then `rfkill list` and include the output of the latter (or both if the former prints an error) into your question? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster can you help me now, I have edited the question

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that this only works after reboot. See https://askubuntu.com/a/845129/175814 for instructions to do that (which may actually be the answer to this question).

Comment: So you are saying I don’t have to go to BIOS settings,. I just have to reboot.. @DavidFoerster

Comment: You won't need to for the sake of *this* trial but it's definitely another thing worth trying before I'm convinced whether this is the answer or not.

Comment: i have done that. it is still the same @DavidFoerster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78214/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-praphulla-koushik).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have send you message in chat room

Comment: I had very bad experiences with `RT3290` on HP computers. The only "solutions" that worked definitely for me (after months of trials and reompiling drivers and wifi that worked and didn't apparently in a random way) was to buy an Intel card and replace it.

Comment: @dadexix86 what intel card are you talking about? I dont know much about computers. sorry

Comment: It's not an operation that I would suggest to someone who has never opened. That being said, on Ebay you can find plenty of wifi cards that are correctly compatible with the model of your motherboard. You just have to pick one that you might find reliable (google in advance to check if there are known issues with Linux), buy it and when it arrives you open your pc, dismount the old card and replace it with the new one. Before attempting any of this, look for tutorial videos about your model of pc to see how hard it is and to decide if you have the tools and feel confident enough to do it.

Comment: Try to reset BIOS to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The issue of HP wireless being inoperable because of a hard block and therefore the usual wireless key not toggling wireless on and off is long-standing. There are only a few things you can try.

First, try removing the helper module *hp_wmi* and then try to switch the wireless on with the key combination. Checking the comments above, you have tried this and failed.

You could also try:

```
sudo modprobe -r hp_wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
rfkill list all
```

Second, check the user guide for your HP laptop and be certain that the wireless key combination you are using is correct. Be certain that you are not using Fn+F12, for example, if the user guide says it is simply F12. On the other hand, if you are certain you are using the correct sequence, try the *wrong* sequence as an experiment; i.e., use Fn+F12 (or whatever your sequence is) if the user guide says it’s F12 and vice versa.

Next, you can remove the card, tape off pin 20 and re-insert it: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150597

You can, if all these steps fail, file a bug report against the module hp_wmi: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Finally, in many, but not every case, a USB wireless will also be hard blocked for the same reasons. If you want to try one, be certain to try it within a return period.

I regret that there isn’t a better answer for HP laptops.

Comment: I tried first two suggestions. I am not aware of computers and not confident enough to go for "remove the card, tape off pin 20"suggestion