# wifi is disabled in ubuntu 16 in Lonovo

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 in my Lenovo-V310-15ISK. Initially I was not able to see wifi option in network tab. I tried to find solution and I get useful instruction to solve this issue. I followed instruction given in answer https://askubuntu.com/a/708103/91417

After that I can see the option to enable wifi. Even after enabling my wifi I can't be able to see available wifi connection. Wifi is working fine and I can use it in my mobile.

Here is my wifi-info.txt file http://paste.ubuntu.com/23769391/

Any guess what is the issue? Your answer or comment will be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

as per @jeremy31's suggestion here is output of `sudo dmidecode | grep -i version`

`Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6100U CPU @ 2.30GHz
        uCode Version
        TXT ACM version
        MEBx version
        ME Firmware Version
        SKL PCH H Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH H Dx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Bx Hsio Version
        SKL PCH LP Cx Hsio Version
        SA - PCIe Version
    Version: 0ZCN27WW
    Version:

    Version:

    Version: Lenovo V310-15ISK`

Comment: There's an hard lock and the firmware isn't loading. Are you sure you followed this instructions (the most upvoted answer)? -> http://askubuntu.com/a/708103/91417

Comment: @CelticWarrior. Thank you. Yes, I do follow it. With the help of it, I can see `Enable wifi` option. I also tried other things as well earlier. Might be in that I did mistake ? Do I need to remove hard lock ?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thank you for your comment. After your comment I tried with add `ideapd-laptop` to blacklist.config and rebooted machine. It works ! Thank you again.

Comment: Can you add `sudo dmidecode | grep -i version` results to the question as that would help somebody that may submit a kernel patch

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have updated my question with command output. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please file a bug report `ubuntu-bug linux` include that blacklisting ideapad-laptop fixes the wifi and that your machine is identified in dmidecode as `Lenovo V310-15ISK`   There is a quirks table in the source code for ideapad laptop and your model can be added so that the module will not need to be blacklisted- you may notice some FN combos not working