# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS WiFi unstable connection (Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30))

Tags: 14.04, wireless, atheros

Recently I have bought a new laptop with Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
network controller. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS edition. I have already noticed many posts considering connection problems with this device.

My problem is that after the installation of the drivers, if i remember correctly, following [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation) since there are no standard drivers for 14.04, status bar suggest that I am connected to the access point but in reality I have no internet access using wifi connection. This happens after 1 - 5 mins when connected to the access point. When I click the reconnect button, the connection is reestablished and the same thing happens after 1-5mins.

<strike>Using ethernet connection, I always have a stable internet connection. This has been hapenning for a long time now. First I thought it was happening at my university wpa-enterprise network only but now I noticed the problem persists everywhere even in the personal network at my parents house, although signal seems to always be pretty strong. My apartment seems to offer more stable connection but I have been facing the same problem there as well but less frequently. With the old laptop I have had no such problems.</strike>
 At parents house, it was the router and not my laptop. So it seems it is only the eduroam network at my university.

Do you have any suggestions, what to try next? I don't want to upgrade to 16.04 due to some software frameworks I need for my project.

---

Edit

It seems that the problem is only with university wpa-enterprise eduroam network  but other people have reported no such issues. I still do not understand why would this happen

Results of iwconfig show:

> ```
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"fc7c00"  
>           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 54:BE:F7:6D:1E:1F   
>           Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
>           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>           Power Management:off
>           Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
>           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>           Tx excessive retries:2207  Invalid misc:4448   Missed beacon:0
> ```

Comment: Please edit to include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: I would look at results for `dmesg | grep auth` when having issues to see if it is trying to connect to different MAC's