# Wi-Fi disabled/disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

I'm a not talented Ubuntu user and I have a problem with wi-fi and Ubuntu 16.04.

It started with 14.04, when an update failed (it stopped before finishing) and the Wi-Fi disappeared from the networking tab. 
I tried something without success, then I decided to upgrade to 16.04 (via LAN).

By mistake I kept an old configuration file, but everything worked 
well except that Wi-Fi still does not work. I disabled Secure Boot from bios (and tried some other random actions) with basically no effect: while the  **Enable Wi-Fi** option was present in the networking tab, there was the indication **Wi-Fi is disabled** under **Wi-Fi Networks**.
The **Network driver** selected in **Software & Updates > Additional drivers** is **Broadcom 802.11** from `bclwm-kernel-source`.

I tried to follow what is suggested in 
[Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation/708103#708103)

But the only result was that **Enable Wi-Fi** disappeared from the networking menu.

How can I fix it?

Thanks for the comments.

I am afraid that following [Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30) Wi-Fi driver installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation/708103#708103) messed up everything.

I add the result of 
`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma
```

I'm sorry if I'm wrong but I have the impression my question is different from [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules). 
In my case Secure Boot has been disabled from bios since the very beginning.

Additional information
result of `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 939933 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-87-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-87-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-87-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for shim-signed  (1.32~16.04.1+0.9+1474479173.6c180c6-1ubuntu1) ...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-87-generic
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)

Comment: You need to diasble Secure Boot. If you sun `sudo modprobe wl` you will see why.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 - Secure Boot is disabled from bios. `sudo modprobe wl` yields `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument`

Comment: Run `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` and post the output to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 I run the command an re-edited the post with the answer

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. Probably that old backports broke it. The easiest way is to re-install the system and then install Broadcom drivers by `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score -1):

Install `broadcom-sta-dkms` instead
Try the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```

it will work for you 
make sure your internet is on :)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it did not work (I also tried to reboot and restart netw manager). Nothing appeared in the network tab and `sudo modprobe wl` yielded  `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Invalid argument`

Comment: In `Software & updates -> Addidtional drivers` the menu gives as the only alternative `Continue using a manually installed driver`

Comment: install synaptic -  sudo apt-get install synaptic  then you could check inside synaptic what wireless tools works for you

Comment: you could purge bcmwl-kernel-source or could go to wiki.debian.org/wl for further assistance

Comment: i recommend to purge bcmwl-kernel-source