# Wifi problem, could not fetch firmware file, Ubuntu 14.04 with Qualcomm Atheros Device (rev 31)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, atheros, firmware

I went through countless tutorials and similar questions in an attempt to solve this issue, but I still am unable to get wifi working, so I decided to post a new question.

I dual booted my Windows computer with Ubuntu 14.04 because my professor needed me to be compatible with the lab. On my Windows partition, the wifi works. On Linux, it does not work at all. I have tried to sudo-apt get install many backports, and none of them worked. There was an answer [on here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708061/qualcomm-atheros-device-168c0042-rev-30-wi-fi-driver-installation) that almost solved my issue, but I tried to do the command `sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin` and it could not find the files after doing all the other steps.

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235279/my-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-at-all-how-to-troubleshoot) was very helpful but did not solve my issues when I went through the steps.

Here is my output from a bunch of command line queries. I am a new Linux user and I am so lost. Any help would be much appreciated!!

`lspci -nn | grep -i network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:b4200000-b43fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: eth0
       version: 12
       serial: 54:ab:3a:f8:75:37
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 ip=192.168.0.86 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4404000-b4404fff memory:b4400000-b4403fff
```

`lsmod | grep ath`

```
ath10k_pci             40960  0 
ath10k_core           315392  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    32768  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              733184  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              561152  4 wl,ath,mac80211,ath10k_core
```

`dmesg | grep ath`

```
[    1.484608] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    1.727693] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735591] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735596] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    1.735680] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735683] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-4.bin': -2
[    1.735691] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735692] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-3.bin': -2
[    1.735699] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735701] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-2.bin': -2
[    1.735707] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware.bin failed with error -2
[    1.735709] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware (-2)
[    1.735711] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not fetch firmware files (-2)
[    1.735713] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: could not probe fw (-2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `linux-firmware` from `xenial`. It has this firmware.

Run

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.157.12_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After all the solutions I tried, your two simple lines of code fixed it immediately. You really made my day, thank you. :)